# Anybody knows of an example with extjs and a message broker (JMS or something similar)?

Tags: java, ajax, extjs, jms

Anybody knows how to create an application with **extjs** and a **message broker** (**JMS** or something similar)? Any example? I really don't know if it is possible to connect an extjs proxy to a message broker  **producer** and how to **consume** the message.

Your help is really appreciated , thanks in advance.